# Sorting table by columns, how to path method from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I use material ui next table.

I have three components:

- EnhancedTableHead (stateless)
- Table (stateless)
- EnhancedTable (stateful component)

In `EnhancedTableHead` I map through columns and show the label for each `TableCell`.

I need to invoke `onClick` from child `EnhancedHead` to call `EnhancedTable`'s `handleRequestSort`.

**EnhancedTable**

```
const EnhancedTableHead = props => {
    const {columns, onSelectAllClick, order, numSelected, totalCount, onRequestSort } = props

    let createSortHandler = property => event => onRequestSort(event, property)

    return (
        <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                {columns && <TableCell checkbox>
                    <Checkbox
                        checked={numSelected === totalCount && numSelected }
                        onCheck={onSelectAllClick}
                    />
                </TableCell>}
                {columns && columns.map(({key, label, sortable}) =>
                    <TableCell
                        key={key}
                    >
                        <TableSortLabel
                            active={order === key}
                            direction={order}
                            onClick={createSortHandler(key)}
                        >
                            {label}
                        </TableSortLabel>

                    </TableCell>
                )}
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    )
}
```

**Table**

```
const Table = props => {
    const {data, columns, children, selectable, order, selected, onSelect, onDelete, onSearch, onDuplicate, onSort, search} = props

    return (
        <div>
            {selectable &&
                <EnhancedTableToolbar
                    numSelected={selected.length}
                    handleSearch={() => onSearch(data)}
                    value={search}
                    unselectSelected={() => onSelect([])}
                    deleteSelected={() => onDelete(selected)}
                    duplicateSelected={() => onDuplicate([...data, ...selected], [selected])}
                /> }
            <MuiTable >
                {selectable
                    ? <EnhancedTableHead
                        columns={columns}
                        numSelected={selected.length}
                        order={order}
                        totalCount={data.length}
                        onSelectAllClick={() => onSelect( selected.length === data.length ? []: data )}
                        onRequestSort={property => event => onSort(event, property)}

                    />
                    : <TableHead>
                        <TableRow >
                            {columns.map(({label}) =>
                                <TableCell>
                                    {label}
                                </TableCell>)}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                }
.....
```

**EnhancedTable**

```
class EnhancedTable extends Component {
    state = {
        selected: [],
        data,
        order: {
            direction: 'asc',
            by: 'deviceID',
        },
        search: '',
    }

    handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
        const orderBy = property
        let order = 'desc'

        if (this.state.order.by === property && this.state.order.direction === 'desc') {
            order = 'asc'
        }

        const data = this.state.data.sort(
            (a, b) => order === 'desc' ? b[orderBy] > a[orderBy] : a[orderBy] > b[orderBy],
        )

        this.setState({ data, order })
    }

    deleteSelected = () => {
        const {data, selected} = this.state

        this.setState({data: data.filter(item => !selected.includes(item)), selected: []})
    }

    handleSearch = event => {
        const {data} = this.state
        let filteredDatas = []
        filteredDatas = data.filter(e => {
            let mathedItems = Object.values(e)
            let returnedItems
            mathedItems.forEach(e => {
                const regex = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'gi')
                if (typeof e == 'string')
                    returnedItems = e.match(regex)
            })
            return returnedItems
        })
        this.setState({filterData: filteredDatas, search: event.target.value})
    }

     unselectSelected = () => {
         this.setState({selected: []})
     }

    duplicate = (data, selected) => {
        // const {data, selected} = this.state

        this.setState({
            // data: data.filter((item, index) => selected.includes(index)).reduce((p, c) => [...p, {...data[index]}], data),
            // data : [...data, ...selected],
            data : data,
            selected: selected,
        })

    }

handleSelectChange = selected => {
    this.setState({selected})
}

    render = () => {

        const {selected, data, search, order} = this.state

        return (
            <Paper>
                <Table
                    data={data}
                    selectable
                    columns={columns}
                    order={order}
                    search={search}
                    selected={selected}
                    onSelect={this.handleSelectChange}
                    onDelete= {this.deleteSelected}
                    onSort={this.handleRequestSort}
                    onDuplicate={this.duplicate}
                    onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                />
            </Paper>)
    }
}
export default EnhancedTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**EnhancedTable**
key it's column key,

```
onClick={() => onRequestSort(key)}
```

**Table**
onRequestSort(props from EnhancedTable)

```
onRequestSort={key => onSort(key)}
```

**EnhancedTable**

```
handleRequestSort = key => {...}
onSort={this.handleRequestSort}
```